# com_users login redirect issue

Tags: component, redirect

I have a strange issue with my login redirect. It WAS working perfectly, and I'm not sure when it stopped working, but now it leads to a few issues.

So I have a Menu item using **com_users** Login option. I set this to **Guest** so that it is hidden once a user logs in (I have done this many times without issue).

I am mainly using jReviews component on this website, but I can't redirect to anything outside jReviews either. There is NO caching and I can reproduce in multiple browsers in and out of Ingognito.

No matter what I put in the Login Redirect field on the options tab, it just takes you to the Homepage. If you click on ANY menu item after login, you get a **You are not authorized** message.

If I switch the menu item to Public from Guest, I am redirected to the Profile page and there is no error generated. This happens with or without SEF/URL Rewriting turned on.

I am beyond frustrated here. Nothing new was installed during the time from when it was working to not working. My work has been focused on CSS and layout of the jReviews and main template.

There are no overrides for anything other than front-end style and should have no effect on redirections.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using sh404sef with JReviews? If you are and you are using the sh404sef plugin -"Make sure ALL your JReviews menus are set to public access. Otherwise Joomla will find the menus with the maximum access when an Itemid is not specified and it will result in a non-authorized access message. " [https://docs.jreviews.com/?title=Using_sh404SEF_with_JReviews](https://docs.jreviews.com/?title=Using_sh404SEF_with_JReviews)

Comment: are you using the last version of Joomla 3.4.8?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a Menu-Item to be hidden, using Tab "Link Type" > "Display in Menu" set to "No" (3.7). So no need for an hidden Menu anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden menu, add the login page to that menu and leave it set to public.

Create a login module and set your redirect page with the module parameters. Publish the module and have the module set to guest so it disappears after loggin in.

That should resolve your issues.